# Dynamic notify_url not called

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I don't want to create a duplicate question but I cannot find anything similar even though the title is pretty common here :)

Long story short, I'm passing a notify_url for a buy button, the url is public under a .com domain (i can access it using GET/POST) but for some reasons the paypal sandbox does not call it after a test payment is done.

At this moment the only logic I have under the call back is to save the call in a database for logging purpuses so I can clearly see it is not called at all.

I tried to activate/deactivate the IPN notification in my profile and it did not affect the results.  Still not call.

In the IPN history I can see it; in retrying phase and eventually it became Failed.  The callback is correct, no HTTP response code however - it's like the call is not done or the URL is not accessible.  But again, the URL is public hosted on azure so not a localhost or something :p

This is how the button code looks, I'd appreciate any feedback you may have as this is really frustrating. I replace the original site address and business name for privacy reasons.

Can you pls advice if there's any setting that I may be missing?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://beta.example.com/callback/paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxx@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="INVOICE 111">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Comment: `In the IPN history I can see it; in retrying phase and eventually it became Failed....no HTTP response code however` Have you checked for exceptions on your end? That statement seems to say they are, and your end isn't responding...

Comment: I did check- like said, the callback endpoint does nothing, only saves a line in a SAL table, works fine when I POST or GET manually but I get nothing from paypal.  And my IIS logs do not capture any request from paypal (only my requests)

Answer (score 1):

From the code, I see that your notify_url is set to http://beta.example.com/callback/paypal. However when I try to simply enter this address onto my browser, I am getting this URL is not accessible.

The Retrying status on IPN History means that the PayPal has been trying to reach your server, but was unable to. It will keep retrying for a number of 16 times. After 16 times of retries, the status will change to Failed.

I tried to test your URL on our IPN simulator (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator), and I got an error of the URL is not accessible.

Comment: As explained, I replace the original site address for privacy reasons but the URL is accessible from internet

Comment: Alright. Can you try your URL on the IPN simulator see if it would go through?

Comment: Thanks for the hint pp_louis, I tried using the simulator and I have indeed an error: We're sorry, we could not send an IPN.  How can I get more details of what happend behind?  Like said, if I POST to the URL works fine

Comment: I am not sure if this could be cause of the issue, but does your IPN URL using SSL connection? PayPal recently disable SSLv3 due to the recent Poodle case. If your server is still using SSLv3, then that might cause a handshake error that is preventing PayPal reaching your site. Visit this link for more info about it: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182

Comment: It's plain HTTP for now so it shouldnt be a problem, as I didnt ready anywhere that SSL is required.

Comment: Ok, here's my callback URL maybe it helps: http://beta.invoicedaddy.com/callback/paypal

Comment: Can you try this chunk of code, and let me know if IPN could go through?
http://pastebin.com/WiLLPHDv

Comment: Same thing, my callback URL is not contacted by Paypal.  Are you aware of any possible restrictions? I'm only using a Buy button with a notify_url field.

Comment: There wouldn't be any restrictions. And your implementation seems simple enough and shouldn't cause any complex problem. Does your server using any non standard ports? I suspect could be some issue with your sever that is somehow preventing PayPal from reaching your server. Can you deploy to Live and see if it could reach the server? If couldn't, most probably something on your server is preventing PayPal reaching your server.